# Extracting IDs from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array containing arrays with different lengths. These arrays contain objects with some ids as properties like this one below:

```
[
    [{
        docID: 'EP/L007177/1',
        weight: 0.60196078431373
    }, {
        //...
    }, 
    //...
    ], 
    [{
        //...
    }],
    // ...
]
```

Then I have another array with some of the IDs each time.

Example of the other array:

```
docs:[ { ID: 'AS/P003/5' }, { ID: 'EP/L007177/1'} ,......]
```

How can I extract the (unique) numbers of the indexes in the original array that contain the IDs I have in the other array?

I made this function, but it does work properly if I give only one ID to it:

```
var getTopics = function (Ids, Data) {
    var indexes = [];
    Data.forEach(function(d, i) {
        d.forEach(function(f) {             
            if ((Ids.indexOf(f.docID) > -1) && (indexes.indexOf(i) === -1)) {
                indexes.push(i);
            }                   
        });
    });
    return indexes;
}
```

if I do:

```
docs.forEach(function(o) {
    list = gettopics(o.ID,Dataa) 
})
```

I get only one index, which is not what I expect.

Comment: yes, that is entirely possible.

Comment: `the below array` - there is no array below, did you mean above?

Comment: You can use `Map` for keeping id as a key and indexes as an value and get values as array, you can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Your object doesn't have an `ID` property. Did you mean `f.docID`?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work if you give only one ID? Even if you have one ID, you still have to put it in an array, so that `Ids.indexOf(f.ID)` will work.

Comment: yeah doc.ID, sorry

Comment: It's not clear what your problems is, other than that typo. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Could you add example of your array?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to find Object by ID inside nested arrays (than you may do anything you want with it).

Here is a sample how you can do it:

```
var arr1 = [ 
  [{id: 1, data: 'xxx'}, {id: 2, data: 'yyy'}], 
  [{id: 3, data: 'zzz'}]];

function finById(id) {
  var result = null;
  arr1.forEach((row) => {
    row.forEach((doc) => {
       if(doc.id === id) result = doc;
    })
  })
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function will work (although it is not optimal), but there is a problem in the way you call it:

```
docs.forEach(function(o){ list = gettopics(o.ID,Dataa) })
```

Some issues:

- There are spelling differences (*getTopics* needs a capital T, and *Dataa* probably has an *a* too many)
- You pass a simple value as first argument to *getTopics*, while *getTopics* expects an array for that argument
- The return value of *getTopics* is saved in the variable *list*, but this you do for each item in *docs*, so you will overwrite the previous result each time, and so are left with only the last result.

Instead, build an array that you can pass as first argument to *getTopics*. You can build that array with this expression:

```
docs.map(function(o){ return o.ID })
```

This will collect all *ID* values from *Docs* in an array. Now pass that as first argument to *getTopics*:

```
var list = getTopics(docs.map(function(o){ return o.ID }), data);
```

Now *list* will contain the results you expect, i.e. indices in *Data* that correspond to *ID* values that are found in *docs*.

#### Naming conventions

It is not common practice to name variables with an initial capital letter. This is commonly reserved for naming constructors/classes.

#### Snippet

```js
var getTopics = function (ids, data) {
    var indexes = [];
    data.forEach(function(d, i) {
        d.forEach(function(f) {
            if ((ids.indexOf(f.docID) > -1) && (indexes.indexOf(i) === -1)) {
                indexes.push(i);
            }
        });
    });
    return indexes;
}

var data = [
    [{
        docID: 'EP/L007177/1',
        weight: 0.602
    }, {
        docID: 'EP/L007177/2',
        weight: 0.939
    }, {
        docID: 'EP/L007177/3',
        weight: 0.511
    }],
    [{
        docID: 'AB/L007177/1',
        weight: 0.123
    }, {
        docID: 'AB/L007177/2',
        weight: 0.923
    }, {
        docID: 'AB/L007177/3',
        weight: 0.351
    }]
];

var docs = [
    {ID: 'EP/L007177/3'},
    {ID: 'AB/L007177/2'}
];

var result = getTopics(docs.map(function(o){ return o.ID }), data);

console.log(result);
```